# In angular 1.4.4, why does a change in scope variable propagate to DOM without $watch or $apply?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

```
Scopes provide APIs ($watch) to observe model mutations.

Scopes provide APIs ($apply) to propagate any model changes through the system into the view from outside of the "Angular realm" (controllers, services, Angular event handlers).
```

scope changes is only propagated through `$watch` or `$apply`, however it seems like whenever I change a scope variable within a controller, a new life cycle starts for the DOM belonging to the controller. For example `ng-show` or `ng-if` updates the DOM without `$watch` or `$apply`

Here is the sample [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rb08wgha/2/)

As you can see

```
<div ng-if="authenticateVariable"> without watch or apply</div>
```

Updates whenever `scope.authenticateVariable` is updated

Is this suppose to happen, or is there some subtly I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-if` and `ng-show` have `watch` by default.

Similar for `{{}}`, `ng-model`, `ng-click`, etc. And services like `$timeout`, `$http` apply `$scope.$apply` be default. This so called `two-way binding` of Angular, which is shockingly attractive for developers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's supposed to happen (unless I'm misunderstanding your question).

That's the beauty of AngularJS, the Data & View are so intertwined, when something changes it's immediately reflected onto the View, and vice versa.

`ng-if` must watch your `scope` because it needs to immediately populate if anything changes, and start building that section.

Answer (score 1):

The same documentation you linked says

> During the template linking phase the directives set up $watch expressions on the scope.

With ng-if being a directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) it does exactly that and then has a watch on your scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior in Angular in general.  Angular runs a digest cycle when values on the scope change.  This is what allows for the two-way binding, etc.

`$scope.$apply` is for more manual control over when the digest cycle is run.  As the docs say, you can use `$scope.$apply` to run a digest cycle if something outside of the Angular context changes (and therefore Angular doesn't know about it).  See also `$scope.$digest`.

`$scope.$watch` allows you to manually watch something on `$scope` that Angular either wouldn't otherwise be watching by default or when you want to do additional functionality when a value changes.

TL;DR

What you are seeing is default behavior in Angular, not just 1.4.  The methods you mention are for more fine-grained control over the digest cycle.